# Can not create variable in [setup] robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to create a variable in Test Setup but it make error

```
*** Test Cases ***    
Set Volume Normalisation Level
[Setup]     Run Keywords     ${is_exist}=    Get Exist Element

            ...         AND             Pass Execution If   "${is_exist}" == "True"    Element is not exist
[Template]  Set Volume Normalisation Level
    value=25    actual_value=25
    value=50    actual_value=50
    value=75    actual_value=75
    value=100    actual_value=100
*** Keywords ***
Get Exist Element
    ${present}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Element   xpath://div[text()="Normalization"]
    Return From Keyword     ${present}

Set Volume Normalisation Level
    [Arguments]  ${value}  ${actual_value}
    Drag Vol Norm Slider To  ${value}
    Sleep  .5
    Vol Norm Slider Value Should Be  ${actual_value}
```

=> variable **${is_exist}** not found.

Although I tried with Set Test Variable but it didn't work with keyword

```
*** Test Cases ***    
[Setup]     Run Keywords    Set Test Variable    ${is_exist}    Get Exist Element
            ...         AND             Pass Execution If   "${is_exist}" == "True"    Element is not exist
```

=> `${is_exist}` get a string value: **Get Exist Element**
How can I create variable in Test Setup get value from Keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new user keyword instead of using `Run Keywords`. In your case for example:

```
*** Keywords ***
My Test Setup Keyword
    ${is_exist}=    Get Exist Element
    Pass Execution If   "${is_exist}" == "True"    Element is not exist

*** Test Cases ***
Set Volume Normalisation Level
    [Setup]    My Test Setup Keyword
    # Rest of the test case
```

Comment: Awesome. This is the easiest way!
By the way, my purpose is ignore TEMPLATE and TEARDOWN if keyword in SETUP return false. I tried run keyword Get Exist Element both inside Template and Teardown. It worked.
Is there any better way?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @HieuNguyen Doing it in the setup is the best way I think. That is the righ place to to decisions and preparations prior test run.